# CSS min-width in IE6, 7, and 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I found many answers to this question on Google, but none of them seem to work for all browsers.

I am looking for a CSS-only way to get min-width working on Firefox, IE6, IE7, and IE8. It is well-known that IE does not support min-width, so several hacks are out there to try to emulate the behavior of min-width. Unfortunately, I have not had any luck with them.

Specifically, this is what I'm trying to do:

```
<style type="text/css">
    table.dataTable td {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    table.dataTable td.largeCell {
        white-space: normal;
        min-width: 300px;
    }
</style>

<table class="dataTable">
  <tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Date</td>
    <td>Title</td>
    <td class="largeCell">A large amount of data like a description that could
        span several lines within this cell.</td>
    <td>Link</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Does anyone have a way to get this to work?

Comment: `min-width` is supported in IE >= 7 (although buggy in version 7). It has been supported by Firefox for ages.

Comment: Firefox isn't the problem. It's just that I need a solution that will work across all these browsers.
Also, I'm testing `min-width` in IE8, and it's not working for me.

Comment: To everyone who answered, I'm working on trying out your solutions.

Comment: If it's not working in IE8 you may be in "Quirks mode". Does your HTML have a DOCTYPE and if so which one?

Comment: Here is our doctype: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So it turns out that the necessary hack for getting min-width to work in all browsers isn't as ugly as many make it out to be.

All I had to do was add CSS for a div within the `largeCell` and add an empty div at the end of the cell. The div is only 1px tall, so it doesn't really make the cell look larger than it should be.

```
<style type="text/css">
    table.dataTable td {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    table.dataTable td.largeCell {
        white-space: normal;
        min-width: 300px;
    }

    table.dataTable td.largeCell div {
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        height: 1px;
        width: 300px;
    }
</style>

<table class="dataTable">
  <tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Date</td>
    <td>Title</td>
    <td class="largeCell">A large amount of data like a description that could
        span several lines within this cell.
      <div></div>
    </td>
    <td>Link</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 8):

I use:

```
min-width: 200px;
_width: 200px; /* IE6 */
```

Comment: Is `_width` an IE6-only recognized css value? Unfortunately, this didn't work for me.

Comment: yes you can use _anything to declare an IE6 only property, that was in the days of IE6 hacks however I would recommend you use conditional comments nowdays

Answer (score 4):

```
min-height:expression( document.body.clientHeight +'px');
min-width:expression( document.body.clientWidth +'px');
```

Comment: This one failed for me. You could always become a whitewater rafting guide.  Might not have as many thrills as fighting IE bugs, though.

Comment: he he.. That would be a good job.. I hope I can score more with it ...:) I loved your comment..

Answer (score 3):

By default the Document mode in IE will be Quirks mode

Solution:
add the doctype on top of your html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Answer (score 3):

After so many hack that i have tried none of them works for me for this "min-width" issue, but finally i got its solution for IE 8.

Try to use this: `<!DOCTYPE html>` as your DOC type, this is HTML 5 DOC Type that turns your IE8 page to behave like mozilla or webkit browser.

So apart for min-width and min-height issue, it solves many IE8 problems very easily.

If my post helps you please mail me with your name thats it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding:

```
overflow: visible
```

to the element

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar issue, I needed a site to be 95% unless it was less than 980px.

Nothing here worked, and in desperation I reached out to Bill Burlington's expression answer.  The one mentioned above didn't work for me, but if I used a more robust expression it did!

```
width: expression ( document.body.clientWidth < 980 ? "980px" : "95%" );
```

This basically says if the width is less than 980px, set the width to 980px.  If it's wider, set the width to 95%.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style type="text/css">
.table1 th a {
    display:inline-block;
    width:200px";
}
</style>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th><a>title1</a></th>
        <th><a>title2</a></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```