# css/html not working on internet explorer but working on chrome and safari

Tags: html, css

Is there any reason why this wouldnt work on internet explorer, but it works on google chrome and safari

```
body,html {
    min-width:600px;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family:Calibri;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

here is a fiddle for my full code: http://jsfiddle.net/charliejsford/7a2uH/

EDIT:
it seems to only be this part that is not working on IE

```
<header class="ex1">
        <div class="header-left"><img src="images/phone_icon.png" width="323" height="58" /></div>
        <div class="header-right">Shopping Basket</div>
        <div class="logo"><img src="images/logo" width="409" height="138" /></div>
    </header>
```

and then the CSS:

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 800px;
    height: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.ex1 .header-left {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 33%;
    max-width: 190px;
    float: left;
    margin:50px 0 0 70px;
}
.ex1 .logo {
    width: 409px; /* width of the logo */
    margin:10px auto 0 auto;
}
.ex1 .logo img {
    display: block;
}
.ex1 .header-right {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 33%;
    max-width: 190px;
    float: right;
    margin:50px 70px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: what exactly doesn't work? and which version of IE do you use?

Comment: I can't figure out what's wrong either.

Comment: its mainly the header - all floats to the left rather than spread across the header

Comment: IE doesn't support min-width.
[Here is similar question ]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356525/css-min-width-in-ie6-7-and-8

Comment: ah right okk thank you

Comment: Internet Explorer does not support min-width.

Comment: @user125697 `min-width` doesn't support IE7 too. http://caniuse.com/#search=min-width

Comment: @user125697 yup, we don't but old clients do. I can't understand why the hell they want to browse on IE first of all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [html5 new elements (header, nav, footer, ..) not working in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227331/html5-new-elements-header-nav-footer-not-working-in-ie)

Comment: Actually, 6.7% of IE users still use IE6 worldwide.

Comment: It's relevant to any webdesigner/developer who thinks he can just ignore 25% of the chinese population.

Comment: It's not an answer, it's a comment. Also; do whatever the hell you feel like. I'm just trying to stop people from making your mistakes. Also; look into "Progressive Enhancement" if you could ever get off your high horse and accept the fact that someone might be trying to help.

Answer (score 2):

The `<header>` tag is supported in Internet Explorer 9+.