# Change div from width: 100%; to width: 1000 px; when <1000px (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, css, resize, getelementbyid

I am looking for the correct Javascript only (not JQuery) code that will change a div width from 100% to 1000px if the width of the browser is < 1000px. The code will change back to 100% if the browser size is >1000px. I am determined to learn JavaScript before I learn JQuery! I can find load of JQuery solutions but want to learn JS!  In the fiddle I want to change the div element named "red". The reason is because min-width: 1000px; is not supported in ie and I therefore want a working solution. Thank you very much for any help.
Link to fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/Margate/ddENL/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html>

<head>
<title>Positioning</title>

<style type="text/css"> 
#red {position: absolute; margin-top: 100px; width: 100%; min-width: 1000px; height: 400px; background-color: red;} 
#contents {position: relative; top: 10px; width: 1000px; height: 600px; margin: 0px auto; border: 1px solid white;} 
html, body, div {margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;}
</style>

</head>

<body style="background-color: black;">

<div id="red"></div>
<div id="contents"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use: window.onresize = function(event) and window.innerWidth property

Comment: You could use the hack outlined here to avoid using JS, if you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356525/css-min-width-in-ie6-7-and-8

Comment: @PAM `window.innerWidth` is only supported in IE9+ (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.innerWidth) in IE8 and below you have to use `document.documentElement.clientWidth`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript:

```
window.onresize = function() {
    var widthViewport = window.innerWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
    var el = document.getElementById('red');

    if( widthViewport < 1000 ) {
        // Append the classname which specifies the fixed width
        el.className += ' fixed_width';
    } else {
        // Remove the classname that fixes the width at 1000px
        el.className = el.className.replace( /(\b\s*fixed_width\b)+/, '' );
    }
};
```

CSS:

```
.fixed_width{
    width: 1000px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
window.onload = function() {
    var browserWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
    if(browserWidth < 1000) {
        document.getElementById('red').style.width = '1000px';
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

For old ie , you can use javascript in header, extern file or with  `expression` in css.

It allows then to insert javascript inside CSS file that only IE understands.

base line for this would be:

```
 = document.body.clientWidth < 1001 ? "100px" : "auto"
```

In CSS file

```
width: expression( document.body.clientWidth < 1001 ? "100px" : "auto" ); /* set min-width for IE */
```

Comment: yes it is, within external file called via CC , little less when you want to talk to old ... browser :)

Comment: One of the first things I learned when I started to learn web design was that IE was a bit of a diva and had its own set of rules!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ddENL/1/ ?

```
detectResize();
window.onresize = detectResize;

function detectResize(){
    var redElement = document.getElementById("red");
    var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;

    if (windowWidth < 1000){
        redElement.innerHTML = "Less than 1000";
    } else {
        redElement.innerHTML = "More than 1000";
    }
}
```

Comment: For IE8 and lower you'll need to polyfill the `addEventListener` function

Comment: Hello Ben,Thank you for the answer that is what I wanted yes.

Answer (score 1):

```
var ObjRedDiv=document.getElementById('red');  

/** Get Width Of the browser **/
var browserWidth=window.innerWidth || document.body.clientWidth; 

if(browserWidth<1000) 
{
    ObjRedDiv.style.width='1000px';
}
else
{
    ObjRedDiv.style.width='100%';
}
```